# Why `tf.constant_initializer` does not take a constant tensor?

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

It seems pretty silly to me that [Tensorflow has decided to make a `constant_initializer` op that takes only scalar values](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#constant_initializer). It would make a lot of sense to be able to initialize variables with constant tensors:

```
tf.get_variable('some_var', shape = [4,3], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(tf.constant([[0,0,0], [0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0]])))
```

Is using placeholders and `feed_dict` the only way to initialize tensor variables to custom values? This forces one to have declarations and data initializations in separated places, which is a hassle

Comment: constant_initializer takes Python lists and numpy arrays, the [tests](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/78f721a849300d21035f275cc806a617541be360/tensorflow/python/kernel_tests/init_ops_test.py#L190) have just been updated to reflect that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`tf.constant_initializer()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#constant_initializer) function might not accept a [`tf.Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/framework.html#Tensor) as an argument, but [`tf.get_variable()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#get_variable) *does* accept a `tf.Tensor` as its `initializer` argument. This means you can write:

```
v = tf.get_variable('some_var', initializer=tf.constant([[0, 0, 0],
                                                         [0, 0, 1],
                                                         [0, 1, 0],
                                                         [1, 0, 0]]))
```

...which requires even fewer characters!

The reason `tf.constant_initializer()` doesn't take an arbitrary tensor is that it is designed to initialize variables of many different *shapes* with the same constant value for each element. For example, a statement like:

```
v = tf.get_variable('some_var', shape=[15, 37], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(
    tf.constant([[0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 0, 1],
                 [0, 1, 0],
                 [1, 0, 0]])))
```

...wouldn't make much sense. Arguably we could make `tf.constant_initializer()` accept a scalar `tf.Tensor`, and then it would have semantics similar to [`tf.fill()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/constant_op.html#fill), but we haven't had any demand for that yet. Feel free to raise a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues) if it would be useful though!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "tf.constant", do like below, works in TF 1.13

```
tf.get_variable('some_var', shape = [4,3], initializer=tf.constant_initializer([[0,0,0], [0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0]]))
```